# JS regex not capturing

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write a javascript regexp. What I've written so far is

```
function getName(text) {
    var r = /(.*) \(\d+\)/.exec(text);
    if (r && r.length>1) {
        return r[1];
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```

The text is of the format

> Name (possibly containing spaces) followed by a space followed by open
>   parens followed by a number followed by a close parens followed by
>   more text that I don't care about.

Example

> foo bar (123) 1.1/2.2 3.3%

I've tried the above code in a couple of online regexp testers (regex101.com and regexr.com) and it works as I expect, i.e., it matches up to and including the rparen and captures up to but not including the space before the lparen.

When running in Firefox, the match is only the space-lparen-number-rparent and the capture is empty. I tried adding the `gm` flags and putting a `^` anchor, to no avail.

Comment: There capture will get everything leading up to the parenthesized number (`"foo bar"`).  What do you expect?

Comment: @Pointy He wants to capture the number inside the parenthesis.

Comment: Example updated, and no, I don't want to capture inside the parens. It's the text up the the space before the lparen than I want to capture.

Comment: Well that *is* working in Firefox. What makes you think it isn't? I just did it in the developer console, and the result array has the whole string in element 0 and "foo bar" in element 1.

Comment: Specifically I typed `/^(.*) \(\d+\)/.exec("foo bar (123)")` and got the array I described.

Comment: It also works for me when I paste it into the web console directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I saw it using the Opera debugger (I guess that Chrome would have done the job as well).

The source string is read from file, and there was a newline that hadn't been trimmed, so the input text was really

> foo bar\n (123) other stuff

Knowing this, the capture and match what I expect.

(The Opera debugger showed the embedded newline).

Comment: To complement your answer, you can use `\s+` to capture invisible char so that with this regex `^(.*)\s+\(\d+\)` you can achieve your goal.

Answer (score 3):

Your regex seems to be working fine, I tried on Firefox 61, Chrome 68, IE11 and Edge and all of them worked just fine. It seems to me that the executing environment that you are using doesn't support regexes properly.

Here is what I tested:

```
/^(.*) \(\d+\)/
```

So first `^`, then capture everything `(.*)`, then a space char , then you escape parenthesis opening `\(`, match all digits within it `\d+` and finally escape parenthesis closing `\)`.

Use case:

> foo bar (123)

```
[
  "foo bar (123)", // the whole match ^(.*) \(\d+\)/
  "foo bar",       // first capture group (.*)
]
```

Run snippet bellow to test.

```js
var r = /^(.*) \(\d+\)/.exec('foo bar (123)');

console.log(r);
```

> **Note on OP's answer:** To complement @PaulFloyd's answer, you can use `\s+` to capture invisible char so that with this regex `^(.*)\s+\(\d+\)` you can achieve your goal even if there is a extra `\n` with the space.

Comment: Nice answer, but that's not my problem. I want to capture "foo bar", but I don't see why it's not working in Firefox.

Comment: hmm @PaulFloyd which version are you using? By running the snippet did you get `[
  "foo bar (123)",
  "foo bar",
  "123"
]`? I'm using firefox (latest) by the way

Comment: On my desktop (in France, typing this) I'm running the latest Windows Opera (54.0). For my development work (in California via Citrix on Linux) I'm using FF 44.0.2 and 55.2.1). If I load this page in FF then I get an error that stacksnippets.net can't be found.

Comment: Well, it seems that your regex is ok then, but this environment you are running remotely that isn't working properly, have you tried running it on your desktop?

Comment: I'll have a go but it means wrestling with the firewall, which is why I normally do everything via Citrix.